# login logout application on tomcat

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, authentication, logout

I want to build an application on tomcat server where user can login and save/update some data and then logout. Could you please let me know what is the best poosible way of creating login/logout functionality on tomcat and what are the number of users tomcat would support easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [This Link](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/bank.shtml) will provide a good starting point on how to use login and logout.

EDIT 1:
Regarding the number of users Tomcat would support, the real answer depends on the definition of "concurrent", on the Tomcat setup, and on the web app in question.

Tomcat has a maximum number of concurrent threads it uses to service requests; this can be configured in conf/server.xml and is by default set to 50. But even if there are more than 50 concurrent requests, those are simply put in a waiting queue (I think) and will be serviced once threads become available.

But "users" is not the same as "requests". Users do not constantly fire requests to the server, and requests are generally handled quickly (generally no more than 10 seconds, and possibly much quicker). So a lot more users can all be using a web app at the same time before the number of 50 active threads is reached. How many that might be depends on the nature of the web app.